# "AndroidApkSigner" task was not given a value for the required parameter "KeyPass"

Tags: android, visual-studio, build, apksigner

Archiving fails, and the error message I get is:

The "AndroidApkSigner" task was not given a value for the required parameter "KeyPass".

I've never had this problem before. So this happens before I even get to the "Distribute" option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Add your keystore file and keypass on Android package signing option and Add and check your checkbox.[image: Refer this picture]

Comment: And also select release mode and build again it build successfully.

Comment: Is KeyPass the Keystore Password?

Comment: @Thom yes this is the Keystore password.